# Turn off splash screen when using FlutterViewController within existing native app

Tags: swift, flutter

I'm extending our existing Swift iOS app with pieces of our Android app, built in Flutter. It works fine, however when I segue to the FlutterViewController, the splash screen flashes as it loads (Presumably the flutter splash screen). Is there a way to perform the load/segue in the background and only segue once the page is loaded?

Using: 
Swift 4.0, Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set FlutterViewController's splashScreenView to be nil can work.

> Specifies the view to use as a splash screen. Flutter’s rendering is asynchronous, so the first frame rendered by the Flutter application might not immediately appear when theFlutter view is initially placed in the view hierarchy. The splash screen view will be used as a replacement until the first frame is rendered.
>
> The view used should be appropriate for multiple sizes; an autoresizing mask to have a flexible width and height will be applied automatically.
>
> Declaration
>
> @property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIView *splashScreenView;

Comment: You cannot assign the splashScreenView to be nil.

Comment: You can now but you still get a black flash , you can also assign a UIView of your choice

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/ios-flutterviewcontroller-splashscreenview-nullable

Answer (score 0):

You can as of 3.7 set the splashScreenView to nil or another value, but this does not turn it off, you get a black screen flashing with nil, but at least you can have a different launchscreen for each scenario

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/ios-flutterviewcontroller-splashscreenview-nullable